# jQuery bar-rating plugin color variants

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-bar-rating

I am using bar rating. I need color variant in rating.
light to dark color variant.
My code is as below

```
<script src='jquery.barrating.min.js'></script>

<div class="rating-a">
<select id="example">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

```
<script>  
$(function() {
     $('#example').barrating();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any another JQuery barrating plugin that have option to color variant on every level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old question, but interesting.

You haven't specified which theme ("rating-a" doesn't appear to be a standard theme), so I've gone with .br-theme-bars-1to10 as it fits nicely with the requirement, but any theme should be fine.

Essentially, bar rating creates anchors for each bar with the value as `data-rating-value`, eg:

```
<a href="#" data-rating-value="4" data-rating-text="4"></a>
```

So we can use this to add additional css rules based on the attributes, using `[attr=vaue]` css selector, eg:

```
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active[data-rating-value="1"],
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected[data-rating-value="1"] {
    background-color: #f6ede0;
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active[data-rating-value="2"],
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected[data-rating-value="2"] {
    background-color: #f8e4c5;
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active[data-rating-value="3"],
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected[data-rating-value="3"] {
    background-color: #f2cd95;
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active[data-rating-value="4"],
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected[data-rating-value="4"] {
    background-color: #f3ba62;
}
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-active[data-rating-value="5"],
.br-theme-bars-1to10 .br-widget a.br-selected[data-rating-value="5"] {
    background-color: #f3980e;
}
```

Select different colours depending on your requirements of course.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mm65ody4/